# How to configure a List in hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I'm using `Hibernate` mapping to config stages in my application. It's configured that the necessary class (here called Configurator) is injected with the stages.

I have one list containing Object Score:

```
private List<Score>dsScore = new ArrayList<Score>(0);
```

I have a database containing table Score and a list in class Student and student.hbm.xml as:

```
 `<list name ="dsScore" table="SCORE">
                <key> 
                    <column name="SCORE_ID" not-null="true"></column>
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="model.Score"/>      
            </list>`
```

into a file config Student containing it, it not work.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail because from question it is not clear what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `list` hibernate type is collection with persisted ordering. It
   requires explicit mapped column in underlying table for ordering, so
   your mapping is missing `<index>/<list-index>` element. OR you
   should use `bag` (maybe with `order-by` attribute) to get collection
   mapped to java `List` without persisting order. [See docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-indexed)
2. Use `package`
       attribute on `<hibernate-mapping>` instead of qualified class name.

I assume that both `Student` and `Score` classes are in `model` package. The mapping then should look like

```
<hibernate-mapping package="model">
    <class name="Student" table="...">
        ...
        <bag name="dsScore" table="Score" order-by="...">
            <key column="SCORE_ID" />
            <one-to-many class="Score" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```